# There are black stains on the kitchen tissue when I wipe my pan after washing, is it safe to use the pan?

Tags: food-safety, pan, chemistry

After washing my pan with dishwashing liquid, I was wiping it dry with a kitchen tissue and noticed black stains on it. So I washed the pan again with dishwashing liquid and wiped it but the black stains would still show up on the tissue. Also, in the areas of the pan (the exterior) which were only wet and had no dishwashing liquid used on it when wiping it also turned the tissue black.

The pan:

[image]

The kitchen tissue:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This pan looks like uncoated aluminium. It is quite normal for uncoated aluminium to rub off in this way, after all it is relatively reactive, and the reaction products have to go somewhere.

Your pan is safe, this is expected behavior. If you don't want it, you will have to use a different type of pan, such as stainless steel, or aluminium with some kind of surface treatment (PTFE, anodizing, etc.).